# Prevent React Native from caching local images

Tags: react-native

I have an app that makes heavy use of the Image component from React Native.

I understand that caching is good for remote images but I need to load local images which change regularly.

The Image component is caching the files and showing the cached version even when the local files change.

The question is how do I disable caching on local files but keep it for remote URLs (as I have a mix of local and remote)?

I would give a code example but literally it's as simple as

`<Image source={{uri: 'file://image.png'}} />`

Note: These are files that are created and changed by actions in the app so `require('image.png')` will not cut it. I use that for static images all the time and works great but it's static not dynamic.

I've also seen answers about random query params on the end of the string. That's very hacky in general so I wouldn't hire you for a job :) but apart from that it apparently doesn't work.

Cheers in advance!

To be really clear based on commments and answers to far....when the image file changes. It needs to change the image component immediately so caching and state need to be cleared and the new image is displayed.

Comment: Seems the source attribute has a cache attribute with options of reload, force-cache, only-if-reloaded.  I tried reload which may be correcting it but as I switch screens in react-navigation there's no reloads triggering. Be great to hear from someone who has a real world solution

Answer (score 2):

A bit late to answer but you can add the query `"?time=new Date()"` in your variable, like that :

```
 const [profilePicture] = useState(`${baseURL}${user.infoUser.image_profile}?time=${new Date()}`);
```

The main problem with this one is that is gonna refresh the image every time and oso the delay to display the image may be quite high.

Answer (score 0):

Catching would be good for your app,so you don't want to stop. The solution to that sort of problem is to change the name of the image as well as the image itself. Changing the image without changing the name will do nothing.

You could have something like this

```
<Image source={{uri: `file://${imageName}`}} />,
```

that's the only piece of code you have posted so I can't really suggest more than that.

Better still you could store the `imageName` as part of state to be be able to re-render to a different anytime you feel like.

```
<Image source={{uri: `file://${this.state.imageName}`}} />
```

Comment: I asked for it not to be cached so changes would be reflected.

What does your example suggest? Does it trigger reloading when the state changes?

Comment: I had a similar problem sometime back, for changes to reflect make both the image name and image itself dynamic. This could be with or without state depending on your requirements

Comment: I would love to change the image name constantly but there's another part of the app that generates the images. If I keep changing the name I have to keep deleting the old files etc. Becomes a management and performance nightmare.

Comment: I understand your problem, it's pretty difficult one to handle. Try other solutions, if all fails then you have to just do the management though I don't think it's that hard

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that there's no listener for changes on the image resource itself (and I don't think there's an library for that either). The only possible solution if you don't want to change the name of your file, would be to trigger an Event (or a state/redux - change) to force the component to reload everytime you change the Image in your code.

Otherwise you have to write your own library which always listens on image changes and reloads the component evertime something changes.

Comment: That works! I change the key for the image or the URL itself and on ios set cache=reload as a source attribute for the image.

I also realised that I was updating the state before the image was actually saved to disk which made me think it hadn't worked - it was reloading the old image. That slowed me down a bit but I'll accept this as the right answer as triggering a state change will cause a re-render.

Comment: I'm accepting this answer even though it technically isn't an exact answer. It's probably the closest I'll get though and I did manage to solve my problem thanks to it.