# React-Native: Image NOT disappearing on IOS after changing image source to "null"

Tags: ios, react-native, image, state

If I change the state of an image source to "null", the image should disappear, but it doesn't. This issue happens on IOS, but works correctly on Android. I'm using RN v 0.64.2. On a previous version, 0.60.1, this worked correctly for both platforms.

Edit: Also tried with the latest RN version, 0.66.4, and it still doesn't work correctly.

I have created a very simplified test app that reproduces this issue. Code below:

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {View, StyleSheet, Text, Image, Pressable} from 'react-native';

class App extends Component {
    constructor (props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            image_source: require('./test.png')
        }
    }

    removeImage = () => {
        this.setState({image_source: null});
        //this.setState({image_source: require('./test2.png')});
    }

    checkImage = () => {
        alert(this.state.image_source);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <Text style={{marginTop: 200}}>
                    test text
                </Text>
                <Image
                    style={{width: 100, height: 100}}
                    source={this.state.image_source}
                />
                <Pressable
                    style={{width: 80, height: 25, backgroundColor: 'blue'}}
                    onPress={() => this.removeImage()}
                >
                </Pressable>
                <Pressable
                    style={{width: 80, height: 25, backgroundColor: 'red'}}
                    onPress={() => this.checkImage()}
                >
                </Pressable>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
})

export default App;
```

[image]

Clicking the blue rectangle changes the state of the image source to "null" and the image should disappear, but doesn't. The red rectangle verifies the state was changed to "null". I'm able to switch to a different image; that works correctly, just can't remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set image in component life cycle

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
    import {View, StyleSheet, Text, Image, Pressable} from 'react-native';
    
    class App extends Component {
        constructor (props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {
                image_source:null
            }
        }
    
    componentDidMount(){
       this.setState({image_source: require('./test.png')});
    }
    
        removeImage = () => {
            this.setState({image_source: null});
            //this.setState({image_source: require('./test2.png')});
        }
    
        checkImage = () => {
            alert(this.state.image_source);
        }
    
        render() {
            return (
                <View>
                    <Text style={{marginTop: 200}}>
                        test text
                    </Text>
                    <Image
                        style={{width: 100, height: 100}}
                        source={this.state.image_source}
                    />
                    <Pressable
                        style={{width: 80, height: 25, backgroundColor: 'blue'}}
                        onPress={() => this.removeImage()}
                    >
                    </Pressable>
                    <Pressable
                        style={{width: 80, height: 25, backgroundColor: 'red'}}
                        onPress={() => this.checkImage()}
                    >
                    </Pressable>
                </View>
            );
        }
    }
    
    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    })
    
    export default App;
```

if this do not help, we often used this package for projects
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-fast-image

Comment: This did not work.

Comment: In this case try this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/67338239/8602069

Comment: This led me to the correct answer. What ended up working was adding "key={new Date()}" to the image component. Seems hacky to me, but I guess this is just a bug that doesn't have a better solution?

Comment: I think no. React Native's Image component handles image caching like browsers for the most part. If the image is returned with a Cache-Control header than that will determine the caching behaviour. e.g. If the server returns an image with Cache-Control: max-age=365000000 (one year) than React Native shouldn't try to re-download the image for a year (although the cache does have a finite size)